# Serialization of struct with pointers

Tags: go

Having a struct heirarchy like:

```golang
type DomainStore struct {
    Domains []*Domain
    Users []*User
}

type Domain struct {
    Name    string
    Records []*Record
    Owner   *User
}

type User struct {
    Name      string
    Email     string
    Domains []*Domain
}

type Record struct {
    Name      string
    Host      string
}
```

With a single DomainStore having a list of Domain and Users with pointer between Domain and User.

I'm looking for a way to serialize/deserialize to/from file. I have been trying to use gob, but the pointers is not (by design) serialized correct (its flattened).

Thinking about giving each object a unique id and making a func to serialize/deserialize each type, but it seems much work/boilerplate. Any suggestions for a strategy?

I would like to keep the whole DomainStore in memory, and just serialize to file on user request.

**The main problem: How to serialise/deserialize and keep the pointers pointing to the same object and not different copies of the same object**

Both gob and json seems to "just" copy the value of the object and afted deserializasion I end up with multiple independent copies of objects.

Using gob ang json this is what happens:

Before, A & C both points to B:

```
A -> B <- C
```

After deserialization with json/gob:

```
A -> B1 , C -> B2
```

A & C points to to different object, with the same values. But, if i change B1 it's not changed in B2.

--- Update ---

When marshalling i can obtain the memory location of the object and use it as an ID:

```
func (u *User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&JsonUser{
        ID:       fmt.Sprintf("%p", u),
        Name:     u.Name,
        Email:    u.Email,
    })
}
```

And when marshalling the Domain I can replace the

```
func (d *Domain) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        ID       string `json:"id"`
        Name     string `json:"name"`
        User     string `json:"user"`
    }{
        ID:       fmt.Sprintf("%p", d),
        Name:     d.Name,
        User:     fmt.Sprintf("%p", d.User),
    })
}
```

Now I *just* need to be able to unmarshal this which gives me a problem in the UnmarshalJSON need to access a map of id's and their respective objects.

```
func (u *User) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
  // need acces to a map shared by all UnmarshalJSON functions
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried json Marshal/Unmarshal? Are you tied to a particular file format for serialization?

Comment: There is nothing in stdlib that will do this for you automagically. You'll need to retain some mapping of identifiers to values and do custom marshal/unmarshal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using the following method:

1. All the objects are placed in maps in a State object.
2. When the objects in a State object is marshalled, all objects refered to using pointers is replaced with the memory location of the object.
3. When unmarshalled pointers are restored using a global list of previously read objects.

The code will run, and is just to illustrate the method, I'm new to Go, so bear with me.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

type User struct {
    Name  string
    Email string
}
type JsonUser struct {
    ID    string `json:"id"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}

func (u *User) Print(level int) {
    ident := strings.Repeat("-", level)
    log.Println(ident, "Username:", u.Name, u.Email)
}
func (u *User) Id() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%p", u)
}
func (u *User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&JsonUser{
        ID:    u.Id(),
        Name:  u.Name,
        Email: u.Email,
    })
}
func (u *User) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    aux := &JsonUser{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &aux); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    u.Name = aux.Name
    u.Email = aux.Email
    load_helper[aux.ID] = u
    log.Println("Added user with id ", aux.ID, u.Name)
    return nil
}

type Record struct {
    Type     string // MX / A / CNAME / TXT / REDIR / SVR
    Name     string // @ / www
    Host     string // IP / address
    Priority int    // Used for MX
    Port     int    // Used for SVR
}
type JsonRecord struct {
    ID       string
    Type     string
    Name     string
    Host     string
    Priority int
    Port     int
}

func (r *Record) Print(level int) {
    ident := strings.Repeat("-", level)
    log.Println(ident, "", r.Type, r.Name, r.Host)
}
func (r *Record) Id() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%p", r)
}
func (r *Record) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&JsonRecord{
        ID:       r.Id(),
        Name:     r.Name,
        Type:     r.Type,
        Host:     r.Host,
        Priority: r.Priority,
        Port:     r.Port,
    })
}
func (r *Record) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    aux := &JsonRecord{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &aux); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    r.Name = aux.Name
    r.Type = aux.Type
    r.Host = aux.Host
    r.Priority = aux.Priority
    r.Port = aux.Port
    load_helper[aux.ID] = r
    log.Println("Added record with id ", aux.ID, r.Name)
    return nil
}

type Domain struct {
    Name    string
    User    *User     // User ID
    Records []*Record // Record ID's
}
type JsonDomain struct {
    ID      string   `json:"id"`
    Name    string   `json:"name"`
    User    string   `json:"user"`
    Records []string `json:"records"`
}

func (d *Domain) Print(level int) {
    ident := strings.Repeat("-", level)
    log.Println(ident, "Domain:", d.Name)
    d.User.Print(level + 1)
    log.Println(ident, " Records:")
    for _, r := range d.Records {
        r.Print(level + 2)
    }
}
func (d *Domain) Id() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%p", d)
}
func (d *Domain) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var record_ids []string
    for _, r := range d.Records {
        record_ids = append(record_ids, r.Id())
    }
    return json.Marshal(JsonDomain{
        ID:      d.Id(),
        Name:    d.Name,
        User:    d.User.Id(),
        Records: record_ids,
    })
}
func (d *Domain) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    log.Println("UnmarshalJSON domain")
    aux := &JsonDomain{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &aux); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    d.Name = aux.Name
    d.User = load_helper[aux.User].(*User) // restore pointer to domains user
    for _, record_id := range aux.Records {
        d.Records = append(d.Records, load_helper[record_id].(*Record))
    }
    return nil
}

type State struct {
    Users   map[string]*User
    Records map[string]*Record
    Domains map[string]*Domain
}

func NewState() *State {
    s := &State{}
    s.Users = make(map[string]*User)
    s.Domains = make(map[string]*Domain)
    s.Records = make(map[string]*Record)
    return s
}
func (s *State) Print() {
    log.Println("State:")
    log.Println("Users:")
    for _, u := range s.Users {
        u.Print(1)
    }
    log.Println("Domains:")
    for _, d := range s.Domains {
        d.Print(1)
    }
}
func (s *State) NewUser(name string, email string) *User {
    u := &User{Name: name, Email: email}
    id := fmt.Sprintf("%p", u)
    s.Users[id] = u
    return u
}
func (s *State) NewDomain(user *User, name string) *Domain {
    d := &Domain{Name: name, User: user}
    s.Domains[d.Id()] = d
    return d
}
func (s *State) NewMxRecord(d *Domain, rtype string, name string, host string, priority int) *Record {
    r := &Record{Type: rtype, Name: name, Host: host, Priority: priority}
    d.Records = append(d.Records, r)
    s.Records[r.Id()] = r
    return r
}
func (s *State) FindDomain(name string) (*Domain, error) {
    for _, v := range s.Domains {
        if v.Name == name {
            return v, nil
        }
    }
    return nil, errors.New("Not found")
}
func Save(s *State) (string, error) {
    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(s, "", "    ")
    if err == nil {
        return string(b), nil
    } else {
        log.Println(err)
        return "", err
    }
}

var load_helper map[string]interface{}

func Load(s *State, blob string) {
    load_helper = make(map[string]interface{})
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(blob), s); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("OK")
    }
}

func test_state() {

    s := NewState()
    u := s.NewUser("Ownername", "some@email.com")
    d := s.NewDomain(u, "somedomain.com")
    s.NewMxRecord(d, "MX", "@", "192.168.1.1", 10)
    s.NewMxRecord(d, "A", "www", "192.168.1.1", 0)

    s.Print()

    x, _ := Save(s) // Saved to json string

    log.Println("State saved, the json string is:")
    log.Println(x)

    s2 := NewState() // Create a new empty State
    Load(s2, x)
    s2.Print()

    d, err := s2.FindDomain("somedomain.com")
    if err == nil {
        d.User.Name = "Changed"
    } else {
        log.Println("Error:", err)
    }
    s2.Print()
}

func main() {
    test_state()
}
```

This is quite a lot of code and there are to much coupling between the objects and the serialization. Also the global var load_helper is bad. Ideas to improve will be appreciated.

Another approch would be to use reflection to make a more generic solution. Here is an example using this method:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "reflect"
)

func pprint(x interface{}) {
    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(x, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))  
}


var typeRegistry = make(map[string]reflect.Type)

// Register a type to make it possible for the Save/Load functions
// to serialize it.
func Register(v interface{}) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    n := t.Name()
    fmt.Println("Register type",n)
    typeRegistry[n] = reflect.TypeOf(v)
}

// Make an instance of a type from the string name of the type.
func makeInstance(name string) reflect.Value {
    v := reflect.New(typeRegistry[name]).Elem()
    return v
}

// Translate a string type name tpo a real type.
func getTypeFromString(name string) reflect.Type {
    return typeRegistry[name]
}


// Serializeable interface must be supported by all objects passed to the Load / Save functions.
type Serializeable interface {
    Id() string
}

// GenericSave saves the object d
func GenericSave(d interface{}) (string, error) {
    r := make(map[string]interface{})
    v := reflect.ValueOf(d)
    t := reflect.TypeOf(d)
    if t.Kind()==reflect.Ptr {
        t=t.Elem()
        v=v.Elem()
    }
    r["_TYPE"]=t.Name()
    r["_ID"]=fmt.Sprintf("%p", d)
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        f := t.Field(i)
        name := f.Name
        vf := v.FieldByName(name)
//      fmt.Println("Field", i+1, "name is", name, "type is", f.Type.Name(), "and kind is", f.Type.Kind())      
//      fmt.Println("V:", vf)
        if f.Tag != "" {
            store:=strings.Split(f.Tag.Get("store"),",")
            switch store[1] {
            case "v":
                switch t.Field(i).Type.Name() {
                case "string":
                    r[store[0]]=vf.String()
                case "int":
                    r[store[0]]=vf.Int()
                }
            case "p":
                vals:=vf.MethodByName("Id").Call([]reflect.Value{})
                r[store[0]]=vals[0].String()
            case "lp":
                tr:=[]string{}
                for j := 0; j < vf.Len(); j++ {
                    vals:=vf.Index(j).MethodByName("Id").Call([]reflect.Value{})
                    tr=append(tr,vals[0].String())
                }
                r[store[0]]=tr
            }
        }
    }   
    m,_:=json.Marshal(r)
    return string(m),nil
}

// Save saves the list of objects.
func Save(objects []Serializeable) []byte {
    lst:=[]string{}
    for _,o := range(objects) {
        os,_:= GenericSave(o) // o.Save()
        lst=append(lst,os)
    }
    m,_:=json.Marshal(lst)
    return m
}


func toStructPtr(obj interface{}) interface{} {
    vp := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(obj))
    vp.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(obj))
    return vp.Interface()
}

// Load creates a list of serializeable objects from json blob
func Load(blob []byte) []Serializeable {
    objects := []Serializeable{}
    loadHelper := make(map[string]interface{})
    var olist []interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(blob, &olist); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        for _,o := range(olist) {

            var omap map[string]interface{}
            json.Unmarshal([]byte(o.(string)), &omap)

            t:= getTypeFromString(omap["_TYPE"].(string))
            obj := reflect.New(t).Elem() 

            for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
//              n:=t.Field(i).Name
//              fmt.Println(i,n,t.Field(i).Type.Name())

                if t.Field(i).Tag != "" {
                    store:=strings.Split(t.Field(i).Tag.Get("store"),",")
//                  fmt.Println(store)
                    switch store[1] {
                    case "v":
                        switch t.Field(i).Type.Name() {
                        case "string":
                            obj.FieldByIndex([]int{i}).SetString(omap[store[0]].(string))
                        case "int":
                            obj.FieldByIndex([]int{i}).SetInt(int64(omap[store[0]].(float64)))
                        }
                    case "p":
                        nObj:=loadHelper[omap[store[0]].(string)]
                        obj.FieldByIndex([]int{i}).Set(reflect.ValueOf(nObj.(*User)))
                    case "lp":
                        ptrItemType:=t.Field(i).Type.Elem()
                        slice := reflect.Zero(reflect.SliceOf(  ptrItemType /* reflect.TypeOf( &Record{} ) */  ))//.Interface()
                        for _, pID := range(omap[store[0]].([]interface{})) {
                            nObj:=loadHelper[pID.(string)]
                            slice=reflect.Append(slice,  reflect.ValueOf(nObj)  )
                        }
                        obj.FieldByIndex([]int{i}).Set(slice)                       
                    }
                }
            }
            oi:=toStructPtr(obj.Interface())
            oip:=oi.(Serializeable)
            objects=append(objects,oip)
            loadHelper[omap["_ID"].(string)]=oip
        }
    }
    return objects

}



/* Application data structures */

type User struct {
    Name  string `store:"name,v"`
    Email string `store:"email,v"`
}
func (u *User) Id() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%p", u)
}
func (u *User) Save() (string, error) {
    return GenericSave(u)
}
func (u *User) Print() {
    fmt.Println("User:",u.Name)
}


type Record struct {
    Type     string `store:"type,v"`// MX / A / CNAME / TXT / REDIR / SVR
    Name     string `store:"name,v"`// @ / www
    Host     string `store:"host,v"`// IP / address
    Priority int    `store:"priority,v"`// Used for MX
    Port     int    `store:"port,v"`// Used for SVR
}
func (r *Record) Id() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%p", r)
}
func (r *Record) Save() (string, error) {
    return GenericSave(r)
}
func (r *Record) Print() {
    fmt.Println("Record:",r.Type,r.Name,r.Host)
}


type Domain struct {
    Name    string    `store:"name,v"`
    User    *User     `store:"user,p"`    // User ID
    Records []*Record `store:"record,lp"` // Record ID's
}
func (d *Domain) Id() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%p", d)
}
func (d *Domain) Save() (string, error) {
    return GenericSave(d)
}
func (d *Domain) Print() {
    fmt.Println("Domain:",d.Name)
    d.User.Print()
    fmt.Println("Records:")
    for _, r := range d.Records {
        r.Print()
    }
}


type DBM struct {
    Domains []*Domain
    Users []*User
    Records []*Record
}
func (dbm *DBM) AddDomain(d *Domain) {
    dbm.Domains=append(dbm.Domains,d)
}
func (dbm *DBM) AddUser(u *User) {
    dbm.Users=append(dbm.Users,u)
}
func (dbm *DBM) AddRecord(r *Record) {
    dbm.Records=append(dbm.Records,r)
}
func (dbm *DBM) GetObjects() []Serializeable {
    objects:=[]Serializeable{}
    for _,r := range(dbm.Records) {
        objects=append(objects, r)
    }
    for _,u := range(dbm.Users) {
        objects=append(objects, u)
    }
    for _,d := range(dbm.Domains) {
        objects=append(objects, d)
    }
    return objects
}
func (dbm *DBM) SetObjects(objects []Serializeable) {
    for _,o := range(objects) {
        switch o.(type) {
        case *Record:
            fmt.Println("record")
            dbm.AddRecord(o.(*Record))
        case *User:
            fmt.Println("record")
            dbm.AddUser(o.(*User))
        case *Domain:
            fmt.Println("record")
            dbm.AddDomain(o.(*Domain))
        }
    }
}


func testState() {

    Register(User{})
    Register(Domain{})
    Register(Record{})

    dbm:=DBM{}

    u := &User{Name: "Martin", Email: "some@email.com"}
    dbm.AddUser(u)

    r1 := &Record{Name: "@", Type: "MX", Host: "mail.ishost.dk"}
    r2 := &Record{Name: "@", Type: "MX", Host: "mail.infoserv.dk"}
    dbm.AddRecord(r1)
    dbm.AddRecord(r2)

    d := &Domain{User:u, Name: "Martin", Records: []*Record{r1, r2}}
    dbm.AddDomain(d)

    x:=Save(dbm.GetObjects())

    fmt.Println("== Saved objects")
//  fmt.Println(string(x))

    fmt.Println("== Loading")

    dbm2:=DBM{}
    dbm2.SetObjects(Load(x))


    u2:=dbm2.Users[0]
    u2.Print()
    u2.Name="KURT"
    u2.Print()

    d2:=dbm2.Domains[0]
    d2.Print()
    d2.User.Name="ZIG"
    u2.Print()

}

func main() {
    testState()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `encoding/json` package

to marshal:

```
// Marshal is a function that marshals the object into an
// io.Reader.
// By default, it uses the JSON marshaller.
var Marshal = func(v interface{}) (io.Reader, error) {
  b, err := json.MarshalIndent(v, "", "\t")
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  return bytes.NewReader(b), nil
}
```

to unmarshal:

```
// Unmarshal is a function that unmarshals the data from the
// reader into the specified value.
// By default, it uses the JSON unmarshaller.
var Unmarshal = func(r io.Reader, v interface{}) error {
  return json.NewDecoder(r).Decode(v)
}
```

Not sure there's more to this,

Another thing you can do is, store all these as json formatted strings.

Comment: I have tried this, but the pointers are not restored.
Before:
A->B<-C
After:
A->B1, C->B2
I end up with the same values not the pointer do not point to the same object.